# reactive expression result different

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry, I'm new for Shiny. I recently trying to use the reactive program to finish one project. But now I'm facing an issue not able to figure out why this happen.

First, I create a reactive expression which lists all files in one folder.

```
 fullFilenames <- reactive({list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE)})
```

Then, I observe a button event to trigger rescan the files in the folder and update the `updateCheckboxGroupInput`.

I set a breakpoint at `"print("File Scaned")"`.

When we start the app, the Checkbox Group displays all files under folder correctly.

Then I remove/add files under working folder, then click rescan button. But the Checkbox Group does not get updated.

When program stopped at the breakpoint, I checked value "fullFilenames" and "fullFilenames()", and found that fullFilenames been updated, but not fullFilenames(). I trying to understand the logic behind two values are different and find a way how to update the Checkbox Group in a right way.

Can you please give some help on this issue?

Thank you very much.

Refer to below code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

workDir<-c("c:/files")
setwd(workDir)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Tool"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Setup", tabName = "setup", icon = icon("cogs"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName = "setup",
      fluidRow(
        box(width = 12,
          h1("Setup before generate dashboard"),
          p(class = "text-muted",
          br(),
            "Default all files under working directory been selected, you also can choice your desired files.",
            br(),
            br()
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(12, align="center",
              actionButton("rescanFilesBtn","Rescan CSV Files")
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
          box(width = NULL, style = "max-height: 500px", status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
            title = "Change raw CSV files as you like",
            textInput("csvFileFilter","Desired CSV Files", placeholder = "File names, separate by semicolon"),
            checkboxGroupInput("selectedFiles", "",
              choiceValues = NULL,
              choiceNames= NULL,
              selected = NULL
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  fullFilenames <- reactive({list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE)})

  observeEvent(input$rescanFilesBtn, {
    print("Scan Files")
    fullFilenames <- list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selectedFiles", choices = fullFilenames)
    print("File Scaned")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @SBista, updated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code so that you get an updated list after clicking the rescan button.

In the ui part I have changed your `checkboxGroupInput` as follows:

```
    checkboxGroupInput("selectedFiles", "",
                        choices = list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE), 
                        selected = NULL)
```

This is done because the choices cannot be `NULL`.

I have just commented one line in your server code as your reactive value and local variable had the same name, due to which you were not getting any value for `fullFilenames()`

This is the modified server:

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {


      fullFilenames <- reactive({list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE)})

      observeEvent(input$rescanFilesBtn, {
        print("Scan Files")
        # fullFilenames <- list.files(workDir, pattern="*.csv.gz", full.names=TRUE)
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selectedFiles", choices = fullFilenames())
        print("File Scaned")
      })
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Sbista. I think it's the correct way to use the reactive expression. But I tried this before, this will not update the files, all keep same file list as when launching app.

Comment: It seems to work in my case. I'm not sure what the problem is on your end.

Comment: Here is my procedure to reproduce fault: If I just launch the application, then it will display all files under the folder. After that, if I remove some files under the working directory, then click rescan button. It will not show updated file list. BTW, which OS are you tested?

Comment: My procedure is also the same and it works for me. I'm on Windows 7. By the way, I checked for csv file instead of csv.gz.